# Is there a simple mathematical way in which the maximum predator and prey populations of the Lotka-Volterra model can be calculated?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions

I'm currently working on a simulation that applies Euler's method to graph the Lotka-Volterra equations on a scalable graph grid -- unfortunately, due to the way in which I constructed my simulation, it is near impossible for me to dynamically adjust the graph axes. Is there a mathematical way in which these maxima can be calculated -- preferably a formula? A formula + explanation would be really helpful!

The form of the Lotka-Volterra equations that I am using in my program is:
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \alpha x - \beta x y,$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \delta xy - \gamma y,$$where x represents the prey population density and y represents the predator population density (same as the one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations)).

Thanks!

Comment: What data do you have besides the coefficients $\alpha$, etc.? An initial state $(x(t), y(t) = (x_0, t_0)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the Wikipedia article carefully.

The quantity $V =  \delta x - \gamma \log x + \beta y - \alpha \log y$ is constant, so it can be computed before solving the differential equation.

Also the maximum of $x$ is attained when $y = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, so the maximum value $x^*$ satisfies
$$V = \delta x^* - \gamma \log x^* + \alpha - \alpha \log (\alpha/\beta)
$$
and you can compute $x^*$ from that equation numerically.

Similarly the maximum value of $y$ occurs when $x = \frac{\gamma}{\delta}$ and you can compute the maximum of $y$.